# Summation of infinte series

Tags: algorithms, summation, recurrence-relations, power-series, recursive-algorithms

Sir,
          I have three  infinite summation

$A =J_1 \sum_{n=2}^\infty (n-1) f(n-2) \tag 1$ ,    $B =\sum_{n=0}^\infty  f(n) \tag 2$ and  $C =J_2\sum_{n=1}^\infty  f(n-1) \tag 3$, with $f(0)=2,f(1)=5$ , $J_1$ and $J_2$ are constants

**Question**

Can we express $A $ as functions of $B $ and $C $ if possible? Means can we rewrite $A $ using $B $ and $C $ only

**Note**

Hint is that  $\sum_{n=0}^\infty  f(n) $  is a constant called $\psi$ but we are not aware of the value of it. It implies  derivative of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty  f(n) $ is $0$ only  . Thanks

Comment: Note that $J_2\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(n-1)f(n-2)$ is not a function of $n$.

Comment: Typo error..I have edited now

Comment: If you shift indices, you can see that $C = J_2B$, but you can't write $A$ in terms of $B$ and $C$.

Comment: Yes that is obvious in the case of C.. Looking for A actually.. So are you sure,it is an impossible task so that I should not waste time on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write $C$ in full, it is $J_2(f(0)+f(1)+f(2)+...)$, which is the same as $J_2B$.

If you write $A$ in full, it is $J_1(f(0)+2f(1)+3f(2)+...)$.

Now, if I increase $f(3)$ by 1, and decrease $f(4)$ by 1, then the sum $B$ remains the same, but $A$ changes by $+3-4=-1$.  So knowing $B$ (and C) is not enough to know $A$.

Comment: Let me put in this way.. Is there any way we can rewrite $ \sum_{n=0}^\infty n f(n) $ such that we can separate that n from f(n)

Comment: Perhaps $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}f(n)$ is not what you want.  I showed that two different sequences with the same $\sum f(n)$ have different $\sum nf(n)$, so you need more information than $\sum f(n)$.